# Installing .Net Core on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: .net-core

I am trying to install .Net Core on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS by following the guide at

https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#ubuntu

However the second command fails as follows

```
rrr @MHR-Ubuntu-1604-LTS:/etc$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet-release/ xenial main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'

rrr@MHR-Ubuntu-1604-LTS:/etc$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893
Executing: /tmp/tmp.zyXPb1g9Fe/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
apt-mo.trafficmanager.net
--recv-keys
417A0893
gpg: requesting key 417A0893 from hkp server apt-mo.trafficmanager.net
?: apt-mo.trafficmanager.net: Connection refused
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Connection refused
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver unreachable
gpg: keyserver communications error: public key not found
gpg: keyserver receive failed: public key not found
rrr@MHR-Ubuntu-1604-LTS:/etc$
```

I am not convinced this is a networking issue, because I can successfully browse to 
http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net
in the links browser from this virtual machine.

Can anyone suggest what the issue might be ?

Comment: The only thing I can think of: can you browse to the HTTP**S** version of that site, i.e. [https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/](http://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/)?

Comment: Problem traced to external firewall blocking port.